# Concat multiple rows into a single coumn using case statement

Tags: sql, concatenation, case, group-concat, vertica

I have to concat one column with comma seperated values distributed across multiple rows.
Based on row Number I have to concat Text column.
For example for row_num 2 value in text column should be AB,BC

Input

```
Name.   Date      Identifier     Text Row_num   Val
Charles 08/07/18 30565   AB    1       2
Charles 08/07/18     30565   BC    2       4
Charles 08/07/18     30565   CD    3       6
Charles 08/07/18     30565   EF    4   3
Charles 08/07/18     30565   FG    5.  4
Charles 08/07/18     30565   GH    6       5
```

Output  Desired:

```
Name    Date    Identifier  Text              Row_num        Val
Charles 08/07/18      30565     AB                  1         2
Charles 08/07/18      30565     AB,BC               2         4
Charles 08/07/18      30565     AB,BC,CD                3         6
Charles 08/07/18      30565     AB,BC,CD,EF         4         3
Charles 08/07/18      30565     AB,BC,CD,EF,FG      5         4
Charles 08/07/18      30565     AB,BC,CD,EF,FG,GF   7         5
```

Query Used:

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    Date,
    ,Identifier
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 1 THEN Text END)  ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 2  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 3  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 4  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 5  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 6  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 7  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END)
    SUM(val)
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

The problem with this query is it is giving Null value in Text column for row_num 2,3,4,5,7. Hence not able to get desired output

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    Date,
    ,Identifier
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 1 THEN Text END)  ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 2  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 3  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 4  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 5  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 6  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 7  THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END),
    SUM(val)
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

Comment: Note that the OP can't seem to use agg_concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Just add that condition to the `CASE`:

```
SELECT Name, Date, Identifier,
       (MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 1 THEN Text END)  ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 2 AND Text IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 3 AND Text IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 4 AND Text IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 5 AND Text IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 6 AND Text IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN Row_nnum = 7 AND Text IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || Text ELSE '' END)
       ),
      SUM(val)
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: No That will not help. That is giving the same result because for row_num case statement will again process the data instead of taking from derived column (row_num=1) .